# What icon should I use for an attachment for each row in a table?

Tags: icons

I am trying to design a table for a dashboard. At the end of each row, there will be an icon button to download a file associated with the record of that row. I have narrowed down to two options which are *arrow pointing down* and *paperclip* icons, I can't decide which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on the relationship between that file and that data row.

In my opinion, the *arrow pointing down* icon is often used as download and *paperclip* is more exclusively used for attachment. People will be expecting to download the entire data row as a whole with the first one. Where the latter is more about download something that is extra as an "attachment".